# If Statements in R, with a Data Frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

Suppose  I have a data frame with several lines that look like:

```
        User    Lab    Score
         A       1       5
         A       2       6
         A       4       7
         B       1       3
         B       3       4
         C       2       5
```

Then, for lab 1, I want to divide the score by 5, for lab 2, I want to divide the score by 8, for lab 3, I want to divide the score by 7, and for lab 4 I want to divide the score by 9.
How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You want the `switch` function.  See `?switch` for more info

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For data transformation tasks like this, use `ifelse`, which is a vectorised form of selecting from different results based on a condition.

```
df$Score <- with(df, ifelse(Lab == 1, Score/5,
                     ifelse(Lab == 2, Score/8,
                     ifelse(Lab == 3, Score/7, Score/9))))
```

(This assumes you only have 4 Labs.)

Comment: I'll +1 this since the OP hasn't taken that trouble and it is exactly what was asked for. Surprisingly, the unorthodox `factor` approach I took is faster than this. I don't really know how efficient nested `ifelse` statements would end up being if there are many recodings that need to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Here a clean and generalisable solution using `merge`.

```
dat1  <- data.frame(Lab=c(1,2,3,4),
                    coef = c(1/5,1/8,1/7,1/9))
dt.m <- merge(dat,dat1,all.x=TRUE)
dt.m$coef[is.na(dt.m $coef)] <- 1   ## default value
dtt <- transform(dt.m,newScore=Score*coef)


   Lab User Score      coef  newScore
1   1    A     5 0.2000000 1.0000000
2   1    B     3 0.2000000 0.6000000
3   2    A     6 0.1250000 0.7500000
4   2    C     5 0.1250000 0.6250000
5   3    B     4 0.1428571 0.5714286
6   4    A     7 0.1111111 0.7777778
```

**EDIT** If you want to get the same order , structure as the original data :

```
dtt[order(dtt$User),c('User','Lab','Score','newScore')]
 User Lab Score  newScore
1    A   1     5 1.0000000
3    A   2     6 0.7500000
6    A   4     7 0.7777778
2    B   1     3 0.6000000
5    B   3     4 0.5714286
4    C   2     5 0.6250000
```

Comment: I want to +1 this--I like the line of thinking--but I don't like that the order of the resulting `data.frame` is different from the original `data.frame`. Can you modify it somehow to address that?

Comment: +1 for the edit. I would have thought that sticking a `sort` in the `merge` command would have helped, but it doesn't seem to do anything!

Answer (score 0):

This might be pretty unorthodox, but could also be easier to read than a lot of `ifelse`s. `factor` your "Lab" value, specify the divisor as the `labels`, and divide as normal. Assuming the `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
within(mydf, {
  temp <- as.numeric(as.character(factor(Lab, levels=c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                                         labels=c(5, 8, 7, 9))))
  Score <- Score/temp
  rm(temp)
})
#   User Lab     Score
# 1    A   1 1.0000000
# 2    A   2 0.7500000
# 3    A   4 0.7777778
# 4    B   1 0.6000000
# 5    B   3 0.5714286
# 6    C   2 0.6250000
```